# How can I stop a loop from continuing until I receive a response from my HTTP Post? (Ionic 3)

Tags: angular, ionic3

I wrote this following code trying to explain what I want to do. Basically, I have a loop where if a certain condition is met during the loop, an http POST is performed. That POST will return a code, and the code tells me if the POST was successful or unsuccessful. What I want to do is, if I get an error code or if the exception is thrown, I will immediately stop the loop and show an error message. If the code returned is successful, then I will continue the loop and possibly perform another HTTP POST. Where I'm struggling here is with the whole asynchrony thing. The way I wrote that code, I'm assuming that I won't know the result of the HTTP POST in my loop. I need a way that, when the HTTP POST is being performed, the loop won't continue until I get back the result of that POST. I don't have a lot of experience with asynchrony which is why I am asking for help here. Please, any insight you can give me will be greatly appreciated.

```
  sync() {
    //some code here
    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++){
       if(condition){
         //code
         let r = this.syncPost(groupedData, options);
         if(r != 'success') {
           exit loop and show toast with error
         }
       }
    }
  }

  syncPost(sd, options){
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      let result = '';
      this.http.post('path/to/url', sd, options)
      .timeout(2 * 1000 * 60)
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(data => {
        if(returnCode == successful){ //The API returns certain code that tell me that the post was successful
           result = 'success'
        }
        else { //Post returned error code
          result = 'not success [error code]'
        }
        //load.dismiss();
      }, error => {
        result = 'not success [error message]'
      });
      resolve(result);
    });
  }
```

Comment: There is no need to manufacture a new promise with the `http` service. That is considered an anti-pattern. The `http` is asynchroous and non-blocking. That means the JavaScript engine immediately executes the next lines. The JavaScript engine does not "stop loops" to wait for responses. It holds the code block inside the `.subscribe` method and executes it *after* the data returns from the server.

Comment: You should use recursion if you need it to wait. You can call `syncPost` from within the `.subscribe` function.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer is to learn to how to do what you want asynchronously, instead of fighting the design of the framework.

Angular's HttpClient returns Observables, and like the sync/async issue, you should probably learn to go with flow (pun intended), and work with RxJs instead of mixing Promises with Observables - it will be easier in the long-run.

To execute your Http requests asynchronously but sequentially, you can use the rxjs operator 'concat'.

Here's a simple example to get you started. This example simply stops executing requests when an HTTP error is received. Depending on your error handling / return value checking, you may need something a little more complex.

Note that in this example, there are four potential requests, but the third one fails because it will get a 404 (the path does not exist):

Also note that the 'prepareOneRequest' method below does not actually make an http request.
The Observable that it returns is a "cold" Observable - it won't make the request until it is subscribed to, and the 'concat' method will subscribe to one of the Observables at a time, after the previous one completes.

Further note that in "real" code, you wouldn't make the request in an Angular component, you'd put that in a service.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, concat } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  urls = [
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1',
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/2',
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/foo/3', /* this one doesn't exist */
  'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/4'
  ];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  makeRequests() {
    const observables: Observable<any>[] = [];
    this.urls.forEach(url => observables.push(this.prepareOneRequest(url)));
    concat(...observables).subscribe(
      result => {
        console.log('good result: ', result);
      },
      err => console.error('error: ', err)
    );
  }

  prepareOneRequest(url: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(url);
  }
}
```